# What happens if the target of Nautilus's ult teleports?

Tags: league-of-legends

Nautilus's ultimate, Depth Charge, seeks out opponents and pops up everything en route, and finally pops up the target when it reaches him. What happens if the target teleports just as Depth Charge is cast? Does it slowly make its way across the map? Does it have a maximum range? If it has a maximum range, is it possible to evade with the likes of Flash? What is the range?

Comment: I'd love to watch a Depth Charge track someone all the way to their base, if it goes that far. Knowing most target-shots, it probably would still run towards them. There is probably a restriction against the trail hitting the same foe more than once, though.

Comment: @GraceNote It was fun to use Taric's stun on someone just as they were recalling. If you timed it right, the projectile would still be in flight when they teleported, and the dazzle would follow them all the way across the map. Since Dazzle's stun used to be based on distance, this could easily mean 30 seconds stunned in your fountain.

Comment: @Raven I was the *target* of such a long range stun, once, and that was in fact what led me to expect that Depth Charge wouldn't have a range limit, but it's refreshing to see the answer that it does have a limit, which is interesting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When Xypherous did his Dev Diary for Nautilus he answered this question:

> (Forum Goer)Quote: Can you dodge it, or blink over it (referring to the ultimate)?
>
> (Xypherous):If you doge it or blink over it, it will turn around to chase you some more, forever - RUN SINGED RUN.
>
> (Forum Goer) Quote:
>   Master Yi Speed Test Inc.
>
> (Xypherous):I think Rammus stands a better shot of making it halfway across the map before it hits him - :P
>
> (Xypherous):If you can outrun it for 5 seconds or get 2000+ units away from it, it'll just explode on the spot.

Link to the [source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=20822703#post20822703)

Found a video of someone actually managing to outrun Nautilus' ultimate:

Comment: you explain it, but i didn't find some test about teleport. did you know anything about ?

Comment: I've kept my eyes open for one, but haven't found one yet. If I see one I'll edit the answer and add it.

Comment: Thanks, i am looking for it too. is good to make this complete. xD