# What happens when someone teleports when Nautilus' Depth Charge is chasing them?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if the target of Nautilus's ult teleports?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50952/what-happens-if-the-target-of-nautiluss-ult-teleports)

Nautilus' ultimate, **Depth Charge**, fires a shockwave that chases the enemy champion and explodes when it reaches them. What happens if the enemy recalls to base while the shockwave is chasing them?

Answer (score 0):

It has a range. This has happened to me before, and it went about halfway across the map before it just disappeared and took his cooldown.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1872901) from Xypherous, Nautilus' technical designer:

> If they are more than 2000 units away from Nautilus - it will detonate on the spot.

So it will explode after a certain amount of follow-distance.