# Can Nocturne use his Ultimate to scape Nautilus's ult

Tags: league-of-legends

I saw [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50952/what-happens-if-the-target-of-nautiluss-ult-teleports) about Nautilus's ultimate, and the answer shows that it can be beat by Master Yi (in the example).

I was wondering as Nocturne, **it's worth spend my ultimate to run from Nautilus Ult? or it's not worth (the distance still got me)?**

In this video:

it shows that you can use flash to interrupt the ultimate in the middle air. So I could jump near to an enemy and flash to avoid contact with him, so I could scape from Nautilus ultimate and don't need to engage in another fight.

Comment: note: Duskbringer will consume this. It happens at the time the charge gets to you, not when he picks a target, so it's fairly easy to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

I have not actually tested it, but the [League of Legends wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nocturne_the_Eternal_Nightmare) says that nocturne's ultimate range is 2000 / 2750 / 3500.  Additionally, the [question you linked to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50952/what-happens-if-the-target-of-nautiluss-ult-teleports) says "If you can outrun it for 5 seconds or get 2000+ units away from it, it'll just explode on the spot."

Assuming that both pieces of information are accurate, it should be possible to use Nocturne's ult to break the 2000 unit limit and escape.  In practice, you'd need sufficiently quick reflexes and a target that is far enough away (Jumping to a target 1800 units away would not work.)  I think it would be pretty rare in a real game situation for both of those requirements to be satisfied, but it should be possible.

The question of whether it's "worth it" or not will vary by situation.  I will note that the cooldown for Nocturne is 160 / 130 / 100, as compared to 120 / 100 / 80 for Nautilus.